# how mongoid create index for test and production environment

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

How mongoid create index for test and production environment?
I mean

```
     rake db:mongoid:create_indexes => environment
```

how to set the environment?

I use mongoid 2.4.9 and rails 3.2.7.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As with other rake tasks for Rails, simply specify RAILS_ENV to rake on the command line,
e.g.,

```
rake db:mongoid:create_indexes RAILS_ENV=test
```

You can tail your log files in another window to watch it happen.

```
tail -f log/*.log
```